# IsMouseOver nâo funciona

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tenho um botao em WPF e mudei o estilo ao passar o mouse em cima (IsMouseOver), mas o problema é que nem sempre que passo o mouse em cima ele muda de estilo. Qdo passo o mouse muito rápido ele continua como se não estivesse com o mouse em cima, assim não mudando o estilo e tbm não aceita o clique.

Estilo do IsMouseOver:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="\Img\on.png" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

E no botao:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BotaoTeste}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="Clicado">Passe o Mouse</Button>
```

O que pode estar de errado?

Comment: Poste todo o código de BotaoTeste.

Answer (score 1):

Sei que esta pergunta já é velha mas segue um exemplo:
Parece complicado mas não é, clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o botão é selecione o menu edit style > edit a copy, ele vai gerar esse codigo original do botão, então nele vc remova a linha que contem o mouse over padrão que esta comentada no código.
RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}

Agora adicione sua regra junto com as outras Triggers padrão como mostra o exemplo abaixo.

Tambem pode usar esta outra solução editando o ControlTemplate conforme o exemplo do link [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)!:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" 
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" 
                               StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"                                            
                                         RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" 
                                         RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" 
                                         SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

                                        <!--RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" -->

                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="\Img\on.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```